# How to fix Mobile Usability Issues (page resources are not loaded) in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, javascript, css, angular.js, render

Our website is responsive but it is showing the below mobile usability issues at Google search console.

1. Content wider than screen
2. Clickable elements too close together
3. Text too small to read

When we try to test live page URL in Google search console in Mobile Usability tab, although the pages appear to be mobile-friendly, sometimes it shows "some page resources are not loaded" i.e. (CSS and JS files) whereas sometimes it shows that "Your page is mobile-friendly" i.e. all resources are loaded. Screenshots attached.

We also have implemented the following:

1. All Meta Tags are well defined
2. We've implemented a CDN for files
3. Reduced the size of the CSS and JS files, as well as images to the bare minimum
4. Provided access to .js and .css files in the robots.txt file
5. The website is working fine on all devices.

What might cause this problem?

### Page loading issues:

[image: page loading issues]

### No loading issues in the same URL:

[image: no loading issues in the same URL]

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that Google Search Console is an automated tool. And like any other tool (especially software), it has bugs, or sometimes just doesn't work well for a split second. If it mostly says you have no loading issues, and you personally confirm there are none, with multiple devices, you are 99% good to go. That's what I would advise to my clients not to touch anything while keeping an eye on it, therefore I feel comfortable to advise this to you. **It is my advice**, not a rule set in stone.